# Log4j - запись в разные файлы в зависимости от размера файла - xml формат конфигурации

Tags: java, log4j

## Не могу настроить Appenders в xml в log4j2.xml. Не работает. Не создаются новые файлы. Что я делаю не так?

```
<pre><code>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile name="rollingFile"
                 fileName="log/template_editor_calc_new.log"
                 filePattern="log/template_editor_calc_%d{yyyy_MM_dd}.log"
                 datePattern="yyyy_MM_dd-HH"
                 maxFileSize = "1KB"
                 ignoreExceptions="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile"/>
    </Async>
</Appenders>
```